# I am trying to source project for python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7

I added this to my `.bash_profile`

```
   export WORKON_HOME= sudo $HOME/.virtualenvs
   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
   source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Then it gives me this message

> NOTE: Virtual environments directory /Users/rawad/.virtualenvs does not exist. Creating...
>   mkdir: /Users/rawad/.virtualenvs: Permission denied

What should I do to fix it? I tried a lot of things online, but nothing work.

Comment: What is `export WORKON_HOME= sudo $HOME/.virtualenvs` supposed to do? Did you mean `export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs`?

Comment: yes sorry I did not delete that before I posted

Comment: Even though it is not working. It is telling me this mkdir: /Users/rawad/.virtualenvs: Permission denied without the sudo.

Comment: `It is letting me that message.` doesn't look like valid code for the `.bash_profile` file.

Comment: A virtualenv is a "virtual" env which you should activate/deactivate. If you're attaching the virtualenv to your bashprofile, that's defeating purpose and you may as well use your own env instead of a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, the code for .bashrc seems to be invalid. Please refer to the [official virtualenvwrapper documentation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). WORKON_HOME should refer to the base directory you want to store environments in (not a command). e.g.:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/virtualenvs
mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Note: I wouldn't recommend using virtualenvwrapper anymore. Just create relative virtual environments and activate them. e.g.:

```
$cd /path/to/python-project
$python -m venv .venv
$source .venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: Okay, I will try to do that do you mean by the bath here where I store my python project?